# How to catch exceptions in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exception

In java I would write,

```
try{
    //do something
}catch(Exception ex){
    //print an error message
}
```

I would like to write a **MySQL procedure/function** to do this.

For example, Insert something into a table. If it fails, display message after catching the exception.
one has a exception block in PL/SQL.
Is it possible in MySQL?

Comment: At least a comment before down voting?

Comment: You have, the following functionality [13.6.7.5. SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html)

Comment: @wchiquito. Yes signal is allowing me to print my error. But it is not similar to a exception block in PL/SQL.
I would like to have try and catch block im mySQL and wanted to know if it is there in mysql

Comment: Currently to achieve something similar a try...catch, is through [13.6.7.2. DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-handler.html) and [13.6.7.5. SIGNAL Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html).

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use [QueryScript](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script.html), a scripting language for SQL, specifically: [query_script_try_catch](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_try_catch.html).